# SQL returning DBnull instead of integer

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to add a record to a table, and for when the record already exists, I want it to return -3. However in my C# code, SQL Server returns `DBNull`. Not sure why, because it returns the `Scope_Identity` no problem. Here is my SQL, any help is appreciated.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertType] 
    @Name varchar(20),
    @UserName varchar(12),
    @returnID int output
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    IF EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM tblTypes 
               WHERE UserName = @UserName AND Name = @Name)
    BEGIN
        RETURN -3 --Already exists
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblTypes (Name, UserName) 
        VALUES (@Name, @UserName)

        SET @returnID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        RETURN @returnID
    END
END
```

Comment: Post your c# code, I get the feeling I know what's wrong

Comment: If you `SET @returnID = -3` instead, how does it go?

Comment: In the if you have a return. In the else you're setting the @returnID. Do the same in the if. An output parameter is different than a return value.

Comment: Think about how it works in C#.  You can have a method set a parameter declared `out` and/or you can return a value from a method.  You access those values differently in the C# code that calls the method.  It's the same in SQL, i.e. an output parameter and a return value are not the same thing, as dman2306 says.  You should rewrite your SQL to use one or the other but not both.

Comment: That was it Brendan, it was looking for the return parameter, but I wasn't setting it on the return. Had to set @returnID =  -3, then return the parameter. Thanks! It's a shame I can't mark a comment as the answer.